# MvvmCross Android shows wrong view

Tags: android, android-fragments, mvvmcross

I have created application using MvvmCross 4.40. It is working on Android. 
I have one activity which shows alot of fragments. In on of fragment when I run camera take photo and then go back framework doesnt show viewmodel which did run camera.

Here is and example

```
public class ViewModelA : BaseViewModel
{
   //...

   private async void OnTakePhotoAsync()
   {
     var photo = await MediaManager.TakePhotoAsync(CameraOptions.Default);
     //rest code is exectued but another viewmodels is getting initialized

   }
}
```

MediaManager is my class which creates Activity then in this activity runs camera, take photo and call Finish().

Does anoyone faced similar issue?

Comment: You cannot create views MvvmCross is not aware of.  If you try to create an activity without Mvvmcross, the result might be weird.

Comment: So the solution would be if my TakePhotoActivity would run with ShowViewModel() ?

Comment: ShowViewModel will show a ViewModel coupled with a View (which includes your TakePhoto action).  But your TakePhoto action cannot be responsible for the View creation